# Using CLOS class instances as hash-table keys?

Tags: common-lisp, hashtable, equality, clos

I have the following class:

```
(defclass category ()
    ((cat-channel-name
    :accessor cat-channel-name :initarg :cat-channel-name :initform "" :type string
    :documentation "Name of the channel of this category")
    (cat-min
    :accessor cat-min :initarg :min :initform 0 :type number
    :documentation "Mininum value of category")
    (cat-max
    :accessor cat-max :initarg :max :initform 1 :type number
    :documentation "Maximum value of category"))
    (:documentation "A category"))
```

Now, I would like to use this class as a key for a hash-table. The addresses of instances can be easily compared with `eq`. The problem is however, there might be multiple identical instances of this `category` class and I would like the hash-table to recognize this as a key as well.

So, I was trying to overwrite the `:test` argument of the `make-hash-table` function like this:

```
(make-hash-table :test #'(lambda (a b) (and (equal (cat-channel-name a) (cat-channel-name b))
                                            (eq (cat-min a) (cat-min b))
                                            (eq (cat-max a) (cat-max b)))
```

Unfortunately, this is not allowed. `:test` needs to be a designator for one of the functions eq, eql, equal, or equalp.

One way to solve this would be to turn the class `category` into a struct, but I need it to be a class. Is there any way I can solve this?

Comment: Why do you need it to be a class?

Comment: Do you want to use *instances* as the keys, or the class itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a more extensible hash table library, as explained in coredump's answer, but you could also use the approach that Common Lisp takes toward symbols:  you can **intern** them.  In this case, you just need an appropriate interning function that takes enough of a category to produce a canonical instance, and a hash table to store them.  E.g., with a simplified **category** class:

```
(defclass category ()
  ((name :accessor cat-name :initarg :name)
   (number :accessor cat-number :initarg :number)))

(defparameter *categories*
  (make-hash-table :test 'equalp))

(defun intern-category (name number)
  (let ((key (list name number)))
    (multiple-value-bind (category presentp)
        (gethash key *categories*)
      (if presentp category
          (setf (gethash key *categories*)
                (make-instance 'category
                               :name name
                               :number number))))))
```

Then, you can call **intern-category** with the same arguments and get *the same* object back, which you can safely use as a hash table key:

```
(eq (intern-category "foo" 45)
    (intern-category "foo" 45))
;=> T
```

Comment: I'll remember about that, nice approach.

Comment: I think this is an elegant solution to my problem. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.  It just shows you can map slots to conses, which `equalp` hash tables can grok.  But my best guess is that the **op** is aware of this, by mentioning the use of structs, which `equalp` hash tables can grok just as well.

Comment: @Paulo **This doesn't really answer the question.** it doesn't explain a way to get a hash table that hashes based on slot values,but it is an answer to "how can I use clos instances as hash table keys?" This answer is not the only one, but is "make sure that your equivalent instances are eq." And a way to do that is interning them. It's not the only solution, but in many cases it's useful.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, I agree, I didn't downvote it.  But this is not generalizable given the question, so in my opinion, it should not be the accepted answer.  And it leaks without weak hash tables.

Answer (score 7):

1. Don't compare numbers with `eq`, use `eql` or `=`. From [`eq`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_eq.htm#eq) (emphasis mine):

   > Objects that appear the same when printed are not necessarily eq to each other. [...]
   >   An implementation is permitted to make "copies" of characters and numbers at any time. The effect is that Common Lisp makes **no guarantee that eq is true** even when both its arguments are "the same thing" if that thing is a **character** or **number**.
2. You can use the [`genhash`](http://www.cliki.net/genhash) library. First, you define a new hash function (see also [`sxhash`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw61/CLHS/Body/f_sxhash.htm)) and a test function for your type and you associate it with a *test designator*:

   ```
   (genhash:register-test-designator
     'category= 
     (lambda (category) <hashing>)
     (lambda (a b) 
       (and (equal ... ...)
            (= ... ...)
            (= ... ...))))
   ```

   Then, you can define a new table:

   ```
   (genhash:make-generic-hashtable :test 'category=)
   ```

Answer (score 7):

Many Common Lisp implementations provide extensions to the ANSI Common Lisp standard to support different test and hash functions (and a lot more).

[CL-CUSTOM-HASH-TABLE](https://github.com/metawilm/cl-custom-hash-table) is a compatibility layer.